# Highlighting text on PDF page using JQuery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I wonder to know how can we hightlight text and make annotations using JQuery ?
If this feature not available with JQuery , Is there possibility to make it with JavaScript ?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Acrobat reader has a fairly robust API for manipulating .pdf documents ...

... and that API happens to be in Javascript.

Here are a couple of links:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html

http://asserttrue.blogspot.com/2010/07/workaround-for-acrobat-javascripts-lack.html

http://www.evermap.com/javascript.asp

Whether any of this will work in your particular scenario is anybody's guess.

'Hope that helps...

Comment: Ah , Thank you . I planned to convert the PDF pages to images , then manage them as images . what do you think ? Is it a good step to do that .

Comment: If you convert them to images, you'll lose all the flexibility of a text-based format.  You won't be able to highlight text since there will be no text.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done. JavaScript runs on HTML pages and manipulates the DOM.

PDF files are transferred as binary and are viewed using a PDF viewer plugin. Javascript is nowhere in the process.

Comment: Adobe Reader, one common reader, does [support](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/reader/pdfs/reader_overview.pdf) JavaScript embedded in PDFs.  This is distinct from JavaScript running in the browser, though.

Comment: What do you suggest , Can I do this PHP ? Any API that support what I am willing to do

Comment: @MatthewFlaschen, it seems that the support you mention does follow the letter of his question, but probably not the spirit of his question.

Comment: I agree with you , I am wondering to know how to modify the PDF File on the Fly .

Comment: @Im asks, then why are you limiting your search to JavaScript? You should be looking at server side languages.

Comment: Potentially you could tryout pdf.js a viewer for the browser made entirely out of js. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438240/highlight-a-section-inside-pdf-using-pdf-js

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and my solution for now is to use Kineticjs to draw on a PDF ( highlights it's just a transparent rectangle ). Then I'm packing everything (all drawing) into Json string and sending it to the server where I'm using PDFsharp to process and save.