# Highlight a section inside pdf using Pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm currently using pdf.js for my project to render PDFs.

Now there is this tricky task to highlight a section of a PDF page given the coordinates.

#### Example

Given a boundary section like `[(31,35),(40,35),(40,40),(31,40)]` I should highlight the given section with any primary color of choice.

How can I accomplish this task using Javascript and the pdf.js API?

Is it possible or am I sounding overambitious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a better way to achieve this find the co-ordinate of the point in the html page

and then subtract the co-ordinate(position) of `div.textLayer` from it to find the co-ordinate

of the text in the pdf displayed online.

In order to find the co-ordinate of the text in actual pdf find the aspect ratio and you would

get the actual co-ordinate

**example**

if the pdf displayed online is `800x900` and the text co-ordinate

`[(31,35),(40,35),(40,40),(31,40)]`

and the actual pdf size is `612x792`

find the appropriate value of the area in actual pdf like this

`(612/(800 / 31)),(792/(900/35))`

and do this way for all co-ordinate found in online

i.e

`(40,35),(40,40),(31,40)`

### NOTE: -

Might want to check the PDF.js API called [convertToPdfPoint](http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/api/draft/PDFJS.PageViewport.html#convertToPdfPoint)

Comment: do you have any repo or live example of this?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a source yet.

Comment: @Viren do you have any working solution now ?

Answer (score 4):

One of the authors for PDF.js, `cjones`, has stated:

`No, and that’s (highlighting) not like something we would add to pdf.js. That ought to be easy to layer on top of pdf.js.`

**Source**: http://blog.mozilla.org/cjones/2011/07/03/pdf-js-first-milestone/

You will need to implement it yourself if you are interested in using this functionality.

Comment: Your best bet is to look into `canvas.js` in the src folder: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/src/canvas.js. The functions `stroke` and `fill` may prove useful. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this example to show how can be achived, the PDF display with textLayer, only with the updated pdf.js library. If you want the interface of normal pdf web, you have to use viewer.js and implement the listeners.

```js
window.onload = function () {
  // atob() is used to convert base64 encoded PDF to binary-like data.
  var pdfBase64 = atob("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");
  
    function getOutputScale() {
    var pixelRatio = 'devicePixelRatio' in window ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1;
    return {
      sx: pixelRatio,
      sy: pixelRatio,
      scaled: pixelRatio != 1
    };
  }

  window.myState = {
    pdfDoc: null,
    pageNum: 1,
    pageRendering: false,
    pageNumPending: null,
    scale: 1.2,
    canvas: null,
    ctx: null,
    textLayer: null,
  };
  myState.canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var $pdfContainer = document.querySelector("#pdfContainer");
  $pdfContainer.appendChild(myState.canvas);
  myState.ctx = myState.canvas.getContext('2d');
  
  // Create TextLayer Div
  var canvasOffset = myState.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var $textLayerDiv = document.createElement("div");
  $textLayerDiv.classList.add("textLayer");
  $pdfContainer.append($textLayerDiv);
  myState.textLayer = $textLayerDiv;


  /**
   * Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page.
   * @param num Page number.
   */
  function renderPage(num) {
    myState.pageRendering = true;
    // Using promise to fetch the page
    myState.pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
      var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: myState.scale});

      // The following few lines of code set up scaling on the ctx if we are on a HiDPI display
      var outputScale = getOutputScale();
      
      
      myState.canvas.width = Math.floor(viewport.width);
      myState.canvas.height = Math.floor(viewport.height);
      myState.canvas.style.width = Math.floor(viewport.width) + "px";
      myState.canvas.style.height = Math.floor(viewport.height) + "px";

      $textLayerDiv.style.width = Math.floor(viewport.width) + "px";
      $textLayerDiv.style.height = Math.floor(viewport.height) + "px";
      
      let canvasOffset = myState.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      $textLayerDiv.style.top = `${canvasOffset.top}px`;
      $textLayerDiv.style.left = `${canvasOffset.left}px`;

      const transform = outputScale !== 1 ? [outputScale, 0, 0, outputScale, 0, 0] : null;
      
      // Render PDF page into canvas context
      var renderContext = {
          canvasContext: myState.ctx,
          viewport: viewport,
          transform: transform,
      };

      var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);
      
      renderTask.promise.then(() => {
        myState.pageRendering = false;
        if (myState.pageNumPending !== null) {
          // New page rendering is pending
          renderPage(myState.pageNumPending);
          myState.pageNumPending = null;
        }
        
        return page.getTextContent().then((textContent) => {      
          var textLayer =  pdfjsLib.renderTextLayer({
            textContent: textContent,
            container: $textLayerDiv,
            viewport: viewport
          });
          textLayer._render();

        });
      });
    });

    // Update page counters
    // document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = num;
  }
  
  /**
   * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
   * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
   */
  function queueRenderPage(num) {
    if (myState.pageRendering) {
      myState.pageNumPending = num;
    } else {
      renderPage(num);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Displays previous page.
   */
  function onPrevPage() {
    if (myState.pageNum <= 1) {
      return;
    }
    myState.pageNum--;
    queueRenderPage(myState.pageNum);
  }
  /**
   * Displays next page.
   */
  function onNextPage() {
    if (myState.pageNum >= myState.pdfDoc.numPages) {
      return;
    }
    myState.pageNum++;
    queueRenderPage(myState.pageNum);
  }
  // document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);
  // document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);
  
  let urlPDF = "https://www.soundczech.cz/temp/lorem-ipsum.pdf"
  /**
   * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
   */
  pdfjsLib.getDocument({data: pdfBase64}).promise.then(function(pdfDoc_) {
    myState.pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
    // document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;
    
    // Initial/first page rendering
    renderPage(myState.pageNum);
  });
  
  
  
  // Text Higlihter
  function getSelectionCoords() {
    let pageIndex = myState.pageNum;
    let selectedPromise = myState.pdfDoc.getPage(pageIndex).then((_page) => {
      let pageRect = myState.canvas.getClientRects()[0];
      let selectionRects = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getClientRects();
      let viewport = _page.getViewport({scale: myState.scale});
      let selectionRectsList = Object.values(selectionRects);
      
      let selected = selectionRectsList.map(function (r) {
        return viewport.convertToPdfPoint(r.left - pageRect.x, r.top - pageRect.y).concat(
           viewport.convertToPdfPoint(r.right - pageRect.x, r.bottom - pageRect.y)); 
      });
      return selected;
    });
    
    return {pageIndex: pageIndex, coordsPromise: selectedPromise};
  }

  function showHighlight() {
      var {pageIndex, coordsPromise} = getSelectionCoords();
      myState.pdfDoc.getPage(pageIndex).then((page) => {
        var viewport = page.getViewport({scale: myState.scale});;
        coordsPromise.then((coords) => {
          let highlightColor = generateColor();
          
          coords.forEach(function (rect) {
            let bounds = viewport.convertToViewportRectangle(rect);

            var x1 = Math.min(bounds[0], bounds[2]);
            var y1 = Math.min(bounds[1], bounds[3]);
            var width =  Math.abs(bounds[0] - bounds[2]);
            var hight = Math.abs(bounds[1] - bounds[3]);
            
            var el = createRectDiv([x1, y1, width, hight], highlightColor);
            myState.textLayer.appendChild(el);
          });
        });
      });
  }
  
  const generateColor = () => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
  }
  function createRectDiv(boundBox, highlightColor){
      // console.log(randomColor);
      var el = document.createElement('div');
      el.setAttribute('class', 'hiDiv')
      el.setAttribute('style', 'position: absolute; background-color: #'+highlightColor+'; opacity: 0.5;' + 
      'left:' + boundBox[0] + 'px; top:' + boundBox[1] + 'px;' +
      'width:' + boundBox[2] + 'px; height:' + boundBox[3] + 'px;');
      return el;
  }

  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    var length = window.getSelection().toString().length;
    if(length > 0){
        showHighlight();
    }else {
        // Clear All ?!
    }
    console.log();
  });
};
```

```css
#pdfContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.11.338/pdf.min.js"></script>


<div id="pdfContainer" class="pdf-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If selecting text could be sufficient for your needs, you might find an entry for your solution in [SO about highlighting text in PDF.js](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43620823/7763696).

The text is selected via `document.getSelection()`.

Adjustment for color as you said can be accomplished by using

```
<span style="yourColorDefinition">
```

instead of

```
<span class="hightlight">
```