# How can I restyle a word when rendering a pdf with pdf.js?

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

When I runder a pdf with pdf.js I would like to be able to restyle some words (e.g. highlight) is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to highlight words while working with PDF.js

As a page contains

- a canvas (for the rendered content)
- an HTMLDivElement (for the non-rendered text content)

you can use the latter one to select text elements.

Having access to the [Selection API](http://w3c.github.io/selection-api/#extensions-to-window-interface) on your browser, you can get the selection via `document.getSelection()`.

The following code demonstrates how to do that if the selected text does not (internally) span across multiple HTMLElements:

```
var s = document.getSelection();

var oldstr = s.anchorNode.textContent;
var textBeforeSelection = oldstr.substr(0, s.anchorOffset);
var textInsideSelection = oldstr.substr(s.anchorOffset, s.focusOffset - s.anchorOffset);
var textAfterSelection  = oldstr.substr(s.focusOffset, oldstr.length - s.focusOffset);

foo.anchorNode.parentElement.innerHTML
  = textBeforeSelection 
  + "<span class='highlight'>" 
  + textInsideSelection 
  + "</span>" 
  + textAfterSelection;
```

For a selection that spans multiple (internal) HTMLElements you *might* be able to traverse the DOM starting at `s.anchorNode` by successively calling `nextSibling` until you reach at `s.focusNode`.

I say *might*, because elements can be positioned in the document in a different order than the one they have on the view.

Assuming `s.anchorNode` is not `s.focusNode`,

- `s.anchorNode` would be highlighted from 0 to `s.anchorOffset`
- `s.focusNode` from `s.focusOffset` until the end of the node and
- all nodes between them could be highlighted entirely

This works (or at least *might work*) for text nodes - the idea could be extended to non-text nodes by surrounding each non-text node with the highlighting span.